# How do I sort the bookkeeping report by date?

Tags: reports

How do I sort the bookkeeping report by date (descending)?

I have sorted by contribution ID but this isn't exactly by date and when you are looking for a transaction it is easy to assume that it hasn't been made when scanning by date, especially if it is on the next page.

Can export and sort the exported data, but this makes people think the report is not working.

It is #20 on the civicrm demo site dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/20

Comment: It may help others if you provide a link eg to dmaster report - do you mean this one? http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/20?reset=1&output=criteria

Comment: Yes - it is #20 on the civicrm demo site http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/20

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth trying Fuzion's [Extended Report](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport) extension which offers other reports eg "Bookkeeping with extra fields "