# Report with Payment Processor

Tags: civicontribute, civireport, contributions

I'm trying to get a report with the name of the Payment Processor that was used for each online Payment. I'm not able to get this to work. Been though the API trying to track the data but not that familiar where that is stored.

It looks like this data is shown on the Contribution view. "PayPal" on the image is the name of the Processor and other Contributions have the name of my other Payment processor. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: if you are using drupal it may be worth checking if Views can let you build the required report

Comment: AWESOME!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, wanting to reconcile against the PayPal account. 
I'm not sure why there isn't a *Payment Method* column in any of the reports.

I

1. Created a new 'Asset' type financial account under CiviContribute > Financial account. If you leave it as 'Revenue' type it does not appear under the payment processor form list
2. Changed the Financial Account under System Settings > Payment processors.
3. The bookkeeping report from extended reports ([dmaster.demo.civicrm.org](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/20)) has this column, but it cannot sort by transaction date as per [How do I sort the bookkeeping report by date?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25400/how-do-i-sort-the-bookkeeping-report-by-date) so export and sort with the spreadsheet program.

Comment: see my comment above - I added this feature today to Extended Reports.

Answer (score 0):

Try using book keeping report which provides additional filters and fields related to accounting. You can also search transactions based on account being used.

Hth
Pradeep

Comment: I did try the Booking Transactions report but still was not able to get that data. Both are under "Credit Card" Payment method with the "Payment Processor Account" Financial account. I could not find a search function that would be able to do this either.

Comment: Try playing around with Debit and Credit financial account under filters